# Can't Drag and Drop Table to Query (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, ms-office, ssms

I can't Drag and Drop table to query, and I get the error message like this:
[image]

> An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.
>   C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\15.0\ActivityLog.xml

Comment: Did you try to get more information by examining the file as stated in the error prompt ?

Comment: I already found out, mostly not on Microsoft, but even though there are problems that I found in Visual Studio, maybe that is different from my problem

Comment: It's a bug. Appears in SSMS 18.1, too. It will be best to put a ticket here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#known-issues-181

Comment: That kind of critical error can usually only be fixed with a reinstall or a patch.